# CassandraBeamIO conversion Into Pcollection of ROWS

Tags: cassandra, apache-beam-io, apache-beam

I am trying to read Data from Cassandra db using apache beam CassandraIO , my requirement is crating a Pcollection of Rows from cassandra db , currently my code look like this

```java
PTransform<PBegin,PCollection<Row>>transform=CassandraIO.<Row>read()
   .withHosts(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1"))
   .withPort(9042)
   .withKeyspace("\"testDb\"")
   .withMapperFactoryFn(new CassandraRowMapper())
   .withQuery(q)
   .withTable("student")
   .withEntity(Row.class)
   .withCoder(SerializableCoder.of(Row.class));
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: what is the problem? do you get any error, etc.?

Comment: hi @AlexOtt the problem is beam CassandraIO is expecting an entity class in entity method and I am trying to access the rows directly so that i can have a Pcollection<Row> apart from Pcollection<Student>